# How to prevent visual studio from creating a new database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am working with local databases on visual studio 2012. I have just one table where I add information to it using the insert command, and then I display the data in a DataGridView and it displays correctly.

The problem is every time I close the program and open it again, all the database's info gets deleted and nothing is saved.

How can I make visual studio keep the information inside the database between uses?

I tried changing the .sdf file to the one inside the bin/debug folder, but then it doesn't even write to the database. Also, I tried changing the property `copy to output directory` to do not copy and that does not work as well, it only works on copy if newer.

[image]

```
'----------------------
Dim ds As New MedicalDataSet
        Dim x As MedicalDataSet.PatientsRow
        'Dim temp As New MedicalDataSet.PatientsDataTable
        x = ds.Patients.NewPatientsRow

        'x = temp.NewPatientsRow()

        x.patientID = mainID.ToString
        x.firstName = txtFirstName.Text
        x.lastName = txtLastName.Text
        x.dateOfBirth = txtDateOfBirth.Text
        x.phone = txtPhone.Text
        x.email = txtEmail.Text
        x.insurance = txtInsurance.Text
        x.typeOfPlan = cmbPlan.Text
        x.subID = txtSubId.Text
        x.planID = txtPlanId.Text
        ds.Patients.AddPatientsRow(x)

        x.AcceptChanges()
        'ds.Patients.Rows.Add(x)
        ds.AcceptChanges()
        adapter.Update(x)
        adapter.Update(ds)
        'adapter.Update(temp)
        'adapter.Fill(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a dataset? Try calling acceptchanges method to save your new data...

Use dataset.tables(0).acceptchanges ...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I am using a dataset. I don't see that method, I see AcceptChangesDuringUpdate and AcceptChangesDuringFill and they both require a dataset as a parameter. Which one should I use and how should I pass my dataset?

Comment: When I put in the table object, it tells me `Property access must assign to the property or use its value`

Comment: Answer updated, sorry it was the data table within the dataset.  It sounds like you may not be connected to your database...let me know how acceptchanges works...

Comment: Sorry I am still a little confused as I cannot see that method in the dataset. I believe I might be missing something. I have edited the original post so you can see what I am saying.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you, hope you're still there, I have been trying with the code you provided and I have managed to do some stuff that doesn't give me errors and seems to be working, but it won't update the table on the dataset. Anything you can pick out? The comments are different stuff I was trying.

Comment: Hi @user3386436 sorry I am probably on a different time zone.  You are using custom object (adapter, dataset, etc) so the method to commit the changes to your database could be quite different.  Updating changes to the Datatable will not necessarily commit the new row to the database.  It depends how your adapter works.  You could require another object with 'write' capability (to the database), which would presumably include validation.  Can you provide some more documentation on the 'Patient' and associated objects?

Comment: @user3386436 Also check the return value from your adapter.Insert method...What is it?  It might be giving you an error or warning value (if perhaps you are trying to insert a duplicate row, or some other invalid data)

Comment: I have finally figured it out, the problem was not the code, it was that vb insert the table into the bin/debug. I was reading the one from the root folder.It has been working this whole time